# Get GitHub Rest API User info C# code

Tags: c#, api, github

https://api.github.com/users/[UserName] can be accessed via browser. I get a Json result. But I want to retrieve the same information programmatically.

I'm using the below code, which is not working as expected. Please advice.

```
var credentials = 
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:", 
githubToken);
credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
var contents = 
client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/users/[userName]").Result;
```

As a result of the above code, I'm getting "Aggregate Exception".

How to achieve the requirement using c# code??? Please help

Note: Not expecting a solution with Octokit. Need proper c# code.

Comment: You have to make a http GET request to that link. Look online for how to make requests in c#. I don't know which framework you're using.

Comment: Can you provide the `InnerException` information. It should tell you more about where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is the code.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
if (webRequest != null)
{
  webRequest.Method = "GET";
  webRequest.UserAgent = "Anything";
  webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

  try
  {
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
      string reader = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
      var jsonobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader)
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    return;
  }
}
```